# How does std::stringstream handle wchar_t* in operator<<?

Tags: c++, unicode, stl, stringstream

Given that the following snippet doesn't compile:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::wstring(L"abc");
```

I didn't think this one would, either:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << L"abc";
```

But it does (on VC++ at least). I'm guessing this is due to the following `ostream::operator<<` overload:

```
ostream& operator<< (const void* val );
```

Does this have the potential to silently break my code, if I inadvertently mix character types?

Comment: Are you intentionally using `stringstream` instead of `wstringstream`?

Comment: No, it's actually the other way around. I'm using `wstringstream` all the time and sometimes forget to add `L` before the string, especially when writing log messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this have the potential to silently break my code, if I inadvertently mix character types?

In a word: yes, and there is no workaround that I know of. You'll just see a representation of a pointer value instead of a string of characters, so it's not a potential crash or undefined behaviour, just output that isn't what you want.

Answer (score 14):

Yes - you need `wstringstream` for `wchar_t` output.

You can mitigate this by not using string literals.  If you try to pass `const wstring&` to `stringstream` it won't compile, as you noted.